# Forming a cURL command using string concatenation in Python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to form a cURL using string concatenation in Python. I have a custom command and I'm not sure if I can use **requests** for this.

```
cmd='curl -u admin:'+password+' -F file=@'+package+' -F name='+package+' -F force=false -F install=true http://'+ip+':5101/crx/packmgr/service.jsp'
    
print(cmd)
```

Error:

```
curl -u admin:******** -F file=@abc_xyz.zip
 -F name=abc_xyz.zip
 -F force=false -F install=true http://8.8.8.8:5101/crx/packmgr/service.jsp
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
sh: line 1: -F: command not found
sh: line 2: -F: command not found
32512
```

And yes I have tried escape '' as well. Didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Do have line endings in your `password` variable? Try `password = password.strip()` before construncting the command. Or, more likely in `package` variable?

Comment: Nope `password = password.strip()` did not work.

Comment: Now try with `package = package.strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your constructed command has line endings after the `package` variable, try stripping it from extra symbols:

```
package = package.strip()
```